# Problems with installation

Tags: system-installation, elementary-os

I have an Asus laptop (more specifically Zenbook pro 14) and I wanted to install elementary os. When I boot a usb drive with the iso everything works fine until the partition selection. The installer only sees the usb drive and not the pc disk! What can I do?

Comment: When you go into the BIOS/UEFI is there an option to change the disk to to AHCI?

Comment: No, I can't find the option

Comment: I think that's probably the reason why the OS can't see the disks. I've had that problem before on a Dell laptop. You might want to go in the ASUS forums and ask about that.